# sending a variable to an applet from either html or js

Tags: java, javascript, html

Alright so I have been getting quite frustrated with how simple this problem seems but I just can't get it to work. So here goes.

I have an applet that displays survey data from students. The applet is going to be hosted on the the course website https://courselink.uoguelph.ca/shared/login/login.html which is an instance of Desire 2 Learn. So when a student logs in they are supposed to be able to see their specific graph. I have written js code that grabs login info from the server but I cannot get it to be passed to the applet. Here are the things I have tried. The variable by the way is a String.

first just embedding the applet in HTML and giving it a parameter.

```
<applet width="800" height="1000" code="graphRun.class">
<PARAM name="name" value=document.hiddenfield.value>
</APPLET>
```

So I have tried to put a variety of things in the parameter field but they always get returned as just Strings saying for example "document.hiddenfield.value", not what is stored. In this particular example I embedded the js variable in a hidden field then tried to access the field in HTML. I have tried lots of different variation of this and done lots o' googling but I can't seem to pass an non hardcoded **variable** as a parameter.

next I tried running it from javascript

```
var attributes = {code:"graphRun.class", width:800, height:1000} ;
var parameters = output ;
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
```

ouput is the js variable name. The problem with this is that it can't find my code, which is odd because when I run the applet from HTML it doesn't have that problem. The exact error I get is a **ClassNotFoundException**

Any help you could provide for either of these two problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is the parameter coming from? are you executing the applet inside a jsp? is it a request parameter? session? maybe: _<PARAM name="name" value='${requestScope[username]}'/>_ ?

Comment: the parameter is in a html field that is hidden on the page. I don't have much experience with JQuery (which is seems you are using there) so I don't really know what that does. There are two ways I have tried to execute the applet, one is from html and one is from js. The parameter is just a string with student info.

Comment: this is not jquery this is EL that you can use only inside a jsp. Are you executing the applet inside a jsp? or inside an html?  Anyways using javascript you could try _var obj = document.getElementById("myAppletParam").value = document.getElementById("hiddenUserName").value;_. I'm assuming _<PARAM name="name" id="myAppletParam"/>_

Comment: its from an html. and that's essentially what have tried to do. The problem is when I use <PARAM name="name" id="myAppletParam"/>  it returns to the applet "myAppletParam" the word instead of what is stored.

Comment: thats why you use _.value_! and obviously your javascript is not executed before your applet

Comment: no the javascript is executed before the applet. it is the first thing to run because the applet needs the variable that the js code grabs before it can run. I was using your example. What my code actually <PARAM name="name" value="document.getElementById('hiddenfield').value">

Comment: I have tried a few other things as well

Comment: also thanks so much for taking your time to help! =)